# multiple foreign keys to the same table but to different columns fetches models.object

Tags: django, view, model, querying

i have two models which are truck and order and they have a relationship.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Truck (models.Model):

        truck_number = models.CharField(max_length=200);
        condition = models.CharField(max_length=20);
        insurance = models.CharField(max_length=20);
        gps_tracking = models.CharField(max_length=20);
        owner_name = models.CharField(max_length=20);
        id_number = models.IntegerField();
        telephone_number=models.IntegerField();
        driver_name=models.CharField(max_length=30, default=None);
        driver_id_number=models.IntegerField();
        driver_phone_number=models.IntegerField();
        driving_license=models.CharField(max_length=20);
        good_conduct=models.CharField(max_length=30);
        def __str__(self):
            truck_number = self.truck_number
            return truck_number



class Order(models.Model):

    truck_number= models.Foreignkey(Truck,related_name='relation_truck')
    date= models.DateField()
    product=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    depot = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    volume = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    volume_delivered = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    driver_name=models.ForeignKey(Truck, max_length=30,default=None)
    driver_id_number=models.ForeignKey(Truck, related_name='relation_id')
    driver_phone_number=models.ForeignKey(Truck, related_name='relation_tel')
    order_status = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        truck_number = self.truck_number
        return truck_number
```

all the fields with foreign keys are fetching the whole object Truck but not the specific value of the foreign key. like i want truck_number in Order to fetch truck_number only from table Truck and not the whole Truck object.
how can i get the foreign key values instead of the the whole object.

Comment: Not understood your question fully but if you need just selected column value then you can use `values` and `value_list`. Read docs at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#values

Comment: like i want to get the values of truck_number, driver_name,driver_id_number and driver_phone number from table truck to show in table order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment you need something like below:

```
Truck.objects.values_list('id', 'truck_number', 'driver_name', 'driver_id_number', 'driver_phone_number')
```

Comment: where will i put this in the views or admin. cause when i want to give order the form of giving order is ModelForm and i placed it in the django admin. when am filling the order form i want to get the dropdowns of truck_number to contain  all the truck numbers that are in model Truck also the same with the other fields

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it  as webbyfox said:

```
class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    fields = ('truck_number','date','product','depot','driver_name','driver_id_number','driver_phone_number')
    form = OrderForm
    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "truck_number":
            kwargs["queryset"] = Truck.objects.values_list( 'truck_number', flat=True)
        elif db_field.name == "driver_name":
            kwargs["queryset"] = Truck.objects.values_list( 'driver_name', flat=True)
        elif db_field.name == "driver_id_number":
            kwargs["queryset"] = Truck.objects.values_list( 'driver_id_number', flat=True)
        elif db_field.name == "driver_phone_number":
            kwargs["queryset"] = Truck.objects.values_list( 'driver_phone_number', flat=True)
        return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)

admin.site.register(Order, OrderAdmin)
```